# What versions of IIS are available as 64 bit?

Tags: iis

Specifically curious if IIS 5.1 has a 64 bit version, but I'm guessing only IIS 6+ are 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64 bit support comes from IIS 6, which is part of Windows XP x64 and Windows Server 2003.

IIS 7 for Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.5 for Windows Server 2008 R2 are the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there is a 64 bit Windows 2000, but it's pretty rare. I'm not sure if there is a native 64 bit IIS5 for that.

Windows XP 64 bit comes with IIS6 rather than IIS5.1, so I think you might be right.